# When you add a wcf service references, how to generate the wcf configuration under another project?

Tags: wcf

When you add a wcf service references, how to generate the wcf configuration under another project?

Comment: exactly what you want?

Comment: Simply take the `<system.serviceModel>` section of the generated code from adding the reference and add it to the config file of the project you want it in.

Answer (score 0):

1. As said Tim (thanks him, you can upvote him !) you can copy the  section and copy it in **app.config** or **web.config** of the other project
2. **svcutil.exe** can also be used to produce the proxy class and  piece of config.
   svcutil.exe is available in the Framework SDK, or under the Visual studio command line (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools in my computer for instance)

Then in a second step you can add the two pieces in any project of your choice.

```
svcutil.exe http://localhost:8990/Service1/ /out:Proxy.cs /config:App.config
```

Can be useful for software factories.

Regards